# What determines customer satisfaction at the Waddle Dee Café?

Tags: kirby-and-the-forgotten-land

There is a minigame at the Waddle Dee Café where you serve food to customers. My first time playing I got a bonus for 100% customer satisfaction even though I messed up one of the orders. My second time playing I only got 92% customer satisfaction despite not messing up a single order.

What determines customer satisfaction when serving food at the Waddle Dee Café?

[image: Waddle Dee Café results screen]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Customer satisfaction is shown by the Waddle Dee bar at the top of the screen during a gig. It depletes while a customer is waiting for an order or if you get an order wrong. It is partially refilled when an order is served correctly.

[image: tutorial prompt about customer satisfaction]

Answer (score 2):

According to [this article](https://game8.co/games/Kirby-and-the-Forgotten-Land/archives/372619):

> There is a bar above the screen that indicates the customers' satisfaction. It will **gradually decrease as time goes by**, or if you make a mistake giving out an item. It will be game over for you if that bar is completely depleted, so try to be fast but accurate when serving them!

[image: Satisfaction bar]

Or it could be due to *Lunch Rush Time*:

> Lunch Rush Time allows you to see the next customers' order in the last 20 seconds. The Satisfaction Bar depletes much faster in the Lunch Rush Time.

So you don't only have to avoid messing up too many orders, but you need to be fast enough. Since you missed an order and still managed to get 100%, that makes me think that the bar can be filled too, maybe when an order is completed quickly.